# ¿Cómo desencriptar cadena de texto?

Tags: java, jsp, base64

Tengo una información en mi base de datos que están encriptada con AES, la cosa es que tengo que desencriptar esa información para mostrar los datos en un perfil y me está petando con cada intento.

El método que encripta es este:

```
public String encriptarDatos(String cadena){
    String cadenaTexto = "";
    try {
        this.keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128);
        this.key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        this.key = new SecretKeySpec("3H3CvHiXkZA$Ke+KBKu%]mQPCiyAtM".getBytes(),  0, 16, "AES");
        this.aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        this.encriptado = aes.doFinal(cadena.getBytes());

        for (byte b : this.encriptado) {
        cadenaTexto += Integer.toHexString(0xFF & b);
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Encriptar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         return null;
    }
    return cadenaTexto;
}
```

Mi método que desencripta lo tengo así pero no consigo que me de pase del "llego 1":

```
public String desencriptarDatos(String cadena){
    String cadenaDesencriptada = "";
    try {
        this.keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128);
        this.key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        this.key = new SecretKeySpec("3H3CvHiXkZA$Ke+KBKu%]mQPCiyAtM".getBytes(),  0, 16, "AES");
        this.aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        BinaryDecoder decoder = new Base64();

        //byte[] desencriptado = cadena.getBytes("UTF-8");
        //byte[] cosa = decoder.decode(desencriptado);
        System.out.println("llego 1");
        byte[] desencriptado = aes.doFinal(cadena.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("llego 2");
        //byte[] desencriptado = aes.doFinal(cadena);
        cadenaDesencriptada = new String(desencriptado);
        System.out.println("llego 3");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Encriptar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         return cadenaDesencriptada;
    }
    return cadenaDesencriptada;
}
```

He probado mil cosas pero no sé cómo hacer para que me saque el texto desencriptado.

Answer (score 0):

Problemas con `encriptarDatos`:

- Crea una llave en cada ejecución del método que luego no usa.
- Usa una llave incrustada en el código, lo ideal es que la guardes en un lugar
  externo (una variable de entorno, por ejemplo) y luego la cargue el programa.
- El método `aes.doFinal` devuelve un arreglo de bytes. Para que se puedan guardar
  en la base de datos son transformados en un `String` con su representación hexadecimal
  (cada byte como una cadena de longitud dos, con caracteres entre 0-9 y A-F)
  pero si uno de los bytes esta en el rango 00-09 o 0A-0F lo convierte a una cadena
  de longitud 1, lo que hace imposible volver a transformar el resultado a bytes.

En `desencriptarDatos`:

```
byte[] desencriptado = aes.doFinal(cadena.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

`cadena` es la representación de los bytes de la cadena encriptada, entonces
`getBytes` devuelve los bytes de la representación y no de la cadena
encriptada.  Para obtener los bytes de la cadena encriptada hay que hacer el
proceso contrario a lo que hace `encriptarDatos` en el for al final:

```
byte[] cadenaBytes = new byte[cadena.length() / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i += 2) {
    cadenaBytes[i/2] = Integer.valueOf(cadena.substring(i, i+2), 16).byteValue();
}

byte[] desencriptado = aes.doFinal(cadenaBytes);
```